# trying to understand angularjs errors

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to js / angularjs and constantly have trouble figuring out why something is not working.

what does it mean when angularjs gives out this error?:

```
Error: [$injector:cdep] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/cdep?p0=authService%20%3C-%20authInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24compile
```

authService and authInterceptor are both my creations.

Comment: Circular dependency detected, you have injected A into B, and B into A, and maybe not directly, it could be through a dependency of one of the injections.

Comment: if you make your comment an answer, I can close this. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular dependency detected, you have injected A into B, and B into A, and maybe not directly, it could be through a dependency of one of the injections.

Generally it means you need to refactor the injections to break the circular dependency.
Hopefully, the thing that both of them need can be moved into its own service (C), then you can inject C into B, and C into A.